# Does Teams "charge" auto renew - I am hoping they don't!

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

We are interested in purchasing teams for our private use. I see and have discussed the payment option being only a credit card. We wanted to do the annual (120) charge that comes with the ten users.

At work we have a strange setup where we don't purchase software that auto charges us once the year is over. We use a lot of [Atlassian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian) products that allow us to renew when we are ready.

Does the Teams feature auto charge your credit card when the second year comes into play? Crossing my fingers that someone from the "Teams" team says "No, we don't do that"...

If the answer is "No, I can purchase Teams". If the answer is yes...well, then that sucks for me :(.

Comment: Could you clarify how exactly you want this to work? Like you want to be able to manually make the payment every year, or you want to be able to start and stop service as desired (like once the year is up, it just sits in a pending state til you decide to renew)? Technically you can "cancel" the subscription and it continues to the next billing date, at which point it goes into read-only mode for up to 60 days, if that's the kind of thing you're after.

Comment: Other services have this thing *“auto renewal”* that you can turn on or off. If it’s on, things are automatically renewed and the credit card is charged again. If it’s off, then you just get a notification about the expiration before it’s over and then you can decide to renew yourself: If you do it, the subscription will just continue; if you don’t, well then it will just be cancelled when the expiration date comes. A big benefit of the latter is that the credit card information isn’t stored permanently but only used for a one-time purchase.

Comment: Right that is what i am asking poke does so teams give me that option

Comment: Yes animuson I want to manually make he payment if what poke mentioned is not available. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, Stack Overflow for Teams subscriptions are auto-renewing at the end of your subscription period** (either monthly or annual, depending on what you select at signup).

There is a bit of a workaround to this (as pointed out by @animuson) in that you can sign up, have your subscription begin, and then "cancel" your subscription, at which point it will be active until the end of your then-current period.  Once your subscription expires, it will enter a 60-day grace period that you'll have to enter new credit card information and renew your subscription (at which point you can repeat the process.

Comment: Ok this kind of is good i guess. I will probably pay and then cancel right away effectively giving me my year. Thank you.

Comment: That workaround doesn't seem to provide the behavior requested in the comments of *not storing the credit card information* in the first place.